# Get real time updates from Facebook Groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Is there a way to get updates in real time to your own server about posts to a Facebook group? I'm trying to build a service that lets users get SMS messages with any messages that were sent to the group. Is this at all possible now? Without polling?

Answer (score 1):

> You can currently subscribe to updates for these types of objects:
>
> user – Get notifications about particular fields and connections
>   corresponding to user nodes in the Graph API. permissions – Get
>   notifications when your users change the permissions they afford your
>   applications. The fields are like those in the corresponding FQL
>   table. page - Get notifications when pages that have installed your
>   application change their public properties. Note that the page topic
>   is only used for subscribing to changes to public attributes of the
>   page (like name, category, picture etc). This is the same information
>   that is returned by the graph api call
>   https://graph.facebook.com/. You can subscribe to the page's
>   feed in the same way you subscribe to a user's feed - the subscription
>   topic should be 'user' and the subscription field should be 'feed'
>   Note: Not all properties and connections of the user object can be
>   subscribed to.

Read this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ for more infos.

Comment: Page's feed subscription not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try the facebook real time updates, it's a bit tricky to implement, but with the examples provided  you should be fine

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/

Comment: I don't think this API supports groups but can't be 100% certain from the docs. Have you tried this?

Comment: The groups are equivalent to facebook pages here. I think it's possible, but haven't tried with groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can now subscribe to `comments`, `membership`, and `posts`, **but only for Workplace**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/group/